# Are unbaptized RCIA candidates required to celebrate the Sacrament of Reconciliation during the RCIA process?

Tags: catholicism, sin, confession

This question arose after the research that went into [my answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39220/according-to-the-catholic-church-does-abortion-need-to-be-confessed-and-is-it/39273#39273) to [According to the Catholic Church, does abortion need to be confessed, and is it a mortal or venial sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39220/according-to-the-catholic-church-does-abortion-need-to-be-confessed-and-is-it) | by [Terry](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/20243/terry).

Are unbaptized and uncatechized candidates for reception into the full communion of the Roman Catholic Church obligated to celebrate the sacrament of reconciliation prior to their profession of faith?

If no, what is the reason and what do they do with their sins prior to baptism?

Comment: Baptism itself remits prior sins.  Furthermore, all other sacraments, including the sacrament of penance, can be received only by people who have been baptized.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Original sin, definitely; but also personal sin(s)? Definitely not the temporal punishment due to those sins, though.

Comment: @Geremia I disagree, and apparently so do the Councils of Florence and of Trent.  See, for example, the Catholic Encyclopedia entry for "Baptism" at http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02258b.htm#xii , especially the section "Effects of Baptism" and its subsections "The remission of all sin, original and actual" and "Remission of temporal punishment".

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't doubt baptism remits all prior sins, but I couldn't find any magisterial document saying so. thanks

Comment: @Geremia Look at Canon 5 of Session 5 of the Council of Trent (available at https://history.hanover.edu/texts/trent/ct05.html), which begins: "If any one denies, that, by the grace of our Lord Jesus Christ, which is conferred in baptism, the guilt of original sin is remitted; or even asserts that the whole of that which has the true and proper nature of sin is not taken away; but says that it is only rased, or not imputed; let him be anathema."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question [here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/when-do-catechumens-go-to-confession) and the answer is no. If you're baptized, your sins are forgiven, if you die you go straight to heaven.  Priests will often remind their congregations of this tonight and make us all jealous.